# Cannot assign value to variable from Powershell form

Tags: powershell

Using the Microsoft Technet example here and pasted below

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I cannot get it to actually assign the user input to the variable `$x`

I've tried removing the void from this line at the end `[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()` but it appears to always return the Cancel text

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the information in the space below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Comment: I've just realised that the code on this page is very similar and works, but I can't see why the first Technet example doesn't. Possibly because it is PS 1.0?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/creating-a-custom-input-box

Comment: Does changing `$x = ` in the event handler to `$global:x = ` fix things?

Comment: I'll try that. Further reading has pointed out that this is a common issue and its because the original code is out of date and doesn't work passed 3.0.  https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/08/02/weekend-scripter-fixing-powershell-gui-examples/

Comment: From 3.0 onwards PowerShell was built on the Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR), which caused scoping rules to change (along with a lot of other minor things). Despite what Dave Wyatt says, though, it isn't actually that logical (and seems to contradict [the actual documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847849))
that assigning a variable inside an event handler is always done with local scope, *even if* the variable was created outside the event handler first (unlike the code you posted). I hope to one day get to the bottom of this in my copious free time.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - yes that did fix it. Looks like a scope issue then? I've new to PS so i'm unsure about these things! Thanks for your assistance

Comment: I've gone ahead and wrote up an answer. Possibly incomplete, but maybe someone can improve on it.

Comment: That's fantastic. Thank you for your assistance. It has certainly helped me with my current task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked fine in PowerShell 1 and 2, but stopped working in PowerShell 3. PowerShell 3 offered a small set of syntax improvements and the usual new cmdlets, but on a less publicized note, it was rewritten on top of the [Dynamic Language Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd233052), a natural choice for a scripting language.

The move to the DLR changed the [scoping rules](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847849) in a way I don't think is well documented even to this day. Specifically, in a script block (like the one used to create a delegate) assigning to a variable creates a new variable in the scope of the block. This makes sense from the point of view of modularity, but isn't so obvious in a scripting language. In particular, consider the following:

```
$x = 2
&{ 
    Write-Host $x;  
    $x = 3; Write-Host $x;
    Remove-Variable "x"; Write-Host $x
    $x = 3; 
}
Write-Host $x
```

This prints:

```
2
3
2
2
```

Within the block, `x` takes its value from the parent scope, but when we assign it, we're actually creating a new variable in the private scope. When we remove that variable, any references to `x` are from the parent scope again. The assignment to `x` does not affect the value in the parent scope, as we can see from the `Write-Host` outside the block.

This explains why assigning a variable in a delegate "doesn't work": you're actually assigning to a new variable inside the delegate, the value of which is lost when the delegate ends. To assign to the variable in the parent scope, an explicit qualifier is necessary (`$script:x` or `$global:x`).